# Absolutely positioned scrolling view with header

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an absolutely positioned widget for a web-app that looks something like this:

```
+-----------+ <-- top: 10px
| Header    |
| Desc ln 1 |
| Desc ln 2 |
+-----------+ <-- moves down as more lines added to the description 
| Scrolling |
| content   |
|           |
|           |
+-----------+ <-- bottom: 10px
```

Basically it has a header and scrolling content under it.  I want the scrolling content area to get smaller as more lines are added to the description.  I also need the top of the header and the bottom of the scrolling content to be pegged to the top and bottom of the viewport.

Here's my Plunker attempt: http://plnkr.co/edit/LdYl7e7GYhdGiF3NQ0Bv

As you can see, I haven't been able to figure out how to connect the middle line to the height of the header.

I know I could figure out a way to do it with JavaScript but I'd prefer to be able to do it in pure HTML/CSS.

Comment: Your scrolling content must have a fixed height. One of your requirements is that the bottom of the scrolling content must be 10px from the bottom of the screen. When you introduce the final constraint that the area of the scrolling content must change height, while staying 10px from the bottom of the screen, then there is no way but javascript to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use inherited height and display specifities that has `<table>`.

Your demo forked :http://plnkr.co/edit/45f0SCrdrNzHJFZLsa8w?p=preview

Add content either  in `#header` or `<div>` in `#content` or both and see what comes to scroll.

if `#header` becomes taller than window , the all thing will expand and window will scroll.

Only `<div>` in `#content` can scroll inside .

oups, FF had trouble , something kind of messy for it . http://plnkr.co/edit/xBJuqnxBuFwfTV2BAAWl?p=preview